# With retrofit upload image using multipart form but not get the path of the file

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, retrofit

when I am trying to upload an image using the multipart form with this code I am not getting the path of the file which I want to upload to the server.

1. have created an interface like this and I want to upload image using 
   multipart

```
 @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    @Multipart
    @POST("api/updateprofile")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto1(
            @Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Part("v_name") RequestBody name,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
```

2. when I am trying to call this api I am getting response but problem
   in sending file to the server.

```
 RequestBody namePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Narendra");
   File file = new File(filePath);
   RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
   MultipartBody.Part file1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("v_image", file.getName(), filePart);


    APIService apiService = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(APIService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> Call = apiService.uploadPhoto1(token,namePart,file1);
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: @BrijeshMavani: thanks for wanting to edit here. You are right that the quote blocks were inappropriate here, but so is excessive bold. It is best to use styles sparingly, as lengthy bold/italics is harder to read. Please also refrain from adding ASAP begging on behalf of the question author - it is widely regarded as impolite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have Solve This Issue by my self

**Just remove the header part from this interface**

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/updateprofile")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto1(
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Part("v_name") RequestBody name,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
```